# Angular JS using a DB Project and EF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, entity-framework, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a MVC project where the web portion is in Angular JS. It was asked of me to create a DB project which I did. We are now concerned with the Angular JS fetching data. Currently there exists a couple of project in the solution representing EF, and in the web project a Web API that interacts with EF, however it is incomplete. However I was considering using an Angular JS Module, Controller, and Service that will communicate with a MVC controller returning a JsonResult as shown here:
[Angular JS with MVC Example](http://www.dotnet-tutorial.com/articles/angularjs/angular-js-with-mvc-basic-example)

Since I created the DB project, I don't really feel the need for EF, but maybe this is a bad practice.If there are any suggestions on what is the standard practice to best fetch data for Angular JS I would love to know as I'm having a hard time pinning what approach is best for my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: why are  you not using WebApi. I think it is better if you use WebApi. 
If you don't need to EF then don't worry. You can use SQL Server and convert SQL Server data response against Select query into Array or List and then return this as a Output.

Comment: Thanks @KPChundawat for the comment. So you suggest using a WebApi that returns an ArrayList as output? Why specifically an ArrayList, do you have an example to further explain the approach? Thanks.

Comment: Because Its data will very clean as Json or XML format and also easy to bind on front end.

Comment: What's a DB project and why would you choose that over Entity Framework? The scenario laid out in your link is very common. You have a SQL database, entity framework on top of that, an MVC controller action (or web api action) that returns JSON and an angular service (or other client) that taps into that.

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene, a DB project is a particular project type in Visual Studio that lets you source control and gives you various tools to publish, rollback, compare, version control, and so forth. So Steve you agree with the approach in the link? Is EF being used in the example from the link?

Comment: OK, that's different. That's managing your schema changes and has nothing to do with data retrieval. Yes, EF is in your link - it's how you get the data and is by far the most common tool for data retrieval in MVC and Web Api. Alternatives are nHibernate or ADO.NET (yikes). The method in the link is very plausible. A lot depends on your security needs etc. If your serving the data up externally or to mobile clients then web api would make sense. If it's just an intranet app and you have code in place already and want to move to an angular front end it's fine.